# How to get the degrees on a circle for each point

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, math

I am trying to determine the amount of degrees between two points on a circle. I am having trouble doing so. I have looked at other posts but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement it.

I am trying to get the distance between the two in degrees.

Hopefully the model below gives you a better understanding.

Here is the data chart

[image]

```py
def get_angle(x, y):
    #75 being the center circle coordinate
    (dx, dy) = (75-x, y-75)
    angle = degrees(atan2(float(dy), float(dx)))
    if angle < 0:
        angle += 180

    return angle
```

The values it is returning don't seem right as the values are very similar for some reason. Such as 157 and 120 though it clearly shouldn't return that. I am somewhat new to image processing so I could be looking at it wrong.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: "the circle isn't there": if you don't know the center, your question has no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Center coordinates: `cx, cy`
Point coordinates: `ax, ay` for point `A` and `bc, by` for point `B`
Pseudocode for angle:

```
 dp = dot(A-C, B-C) = (ax-cx)*(bx-cx) + (ay-cy)*(by-cy)
 cross = vectorproduct(A-C, B-C) = (ax-cx)*(by-cy) - (ay-cy)*(bx-cx)
 angle = degrees(atan2(cross, dp))
 if angle < 0:
      angle += 180
```

If angle direction is not what you expect, change sign of cross